# Capturar excepciones de librerías externas en VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Quería preguntar sobre qué alternativas hay para capturar excepciones no controladas en un programa en VB.net.

El problema que me surge es el siguiente: Tengo un programa en visual basic en el que utilizo la librería de GMAP.net. Esta librería me proporciona un control de tipo `GMapControl`, que básicamente es un mapa en el que puedo pintar chinchetas y rutas como se hace en Google Maps por ejemplo.

En mi programa, voy creando y borrando chinchetas en tiempo de ejecución, porque simulo que un elemento se está moviendo por el mapa. Nunca he tenido problemas hasta que he empezado a simular el movimiento de N elementos.

Tengo toda la aplicación controlada por bloques `Try..Catch`, pero de manera aleatoria me salta una excepción no controlada que viene de la propia librería de GMap, a la cual no tengo acceso para meterle un `Try..Catch` en la sección de código donde salta la excepción, ya que es una dll externa para mí. La excepción que me salta es del tipo 'Colección modificada', que entiendo que se debe al borrado y la creación de las chinchetas, pero que de alguna manera, los creadores de la librería, en algún punto de su código no lo deben de haber controlado.

Como esta excepción no la puedo Try..Catchear por no poder acceder al código, no consigo encontrar una forma de poder capturar esta excepción, y desconozco si existe alguna forma de poder capturar las excepciones que vienen de librerías externas.

Básicamente lo que sucede es que pierdo el mapa, como si el control del mapa entrase en error. Capturando esta excepción, solo tendría de recrear el mapa con la info que tengo en el sistema, y me extraña que no haya una opción o manera con la que se puedan capturar este tipo de excepciones.

Cualquier ayuda será muy agradecida!

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el evento UnhandledException de la clase AppDomain. En tu formulario principal, puede ser en el constructor, puedes poner esto:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

Donde "MyHandler" es un método como este:

```
void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
{
    var exception = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
    if (!args.IsTerminating)
    {
        // aquí manejas la excepción
    }
 }
```